# Verilog syntax for declaring a wire

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is this a legal declaration in Verilog?

```
wire \n_628_B[-1111111109] ;
```

Answer (score 4):

As odd as it might seem, that is legal syntax.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, Section 5.6.1 "Escaped identifiers".  The following code is legal:

```
module tb;

wire \n_628_B[-1111111109] ;
reg foo;

assign \n_628_B[-1111111109] = foo;

initial begin
    $monitor(\n_628_B[-1111111109] );
    foo = 1;
    #5 foo = 0;
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Because it is so odd, I strongly recommend against using it, if you have a choice.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. Everything after a backslash and before the next whitespace is an identifier in Verilog. So the part in square brackets is not an array size or anything but just part of the signal name. Auto-generated Verilog code (for example verilog netlists) contains such escaped identifiers all the time. I personally would not use it in hand-written code though.